# How do i run the .animate function in jQuery forever?

Tags: jquery, ajax, animation, jquery-1.3.2

```
$(this).css("left","100px");

function endless(){
    $(this).animate({
        left:'-=100px',
    },{
        easing: "linear",
    duration: 5000,
    complete: function() {
        $(this).css('left','100px');
    endless();
        }
    });
};
endless();
```

This is what I tried, but using this approach i can't get stuff moving.
   Im' using jQuery 1.3.2.
   Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the parameters to animate wrong.  It doesn't take an options hash, just the actual options for easing, duration, and a callback.  Also, you need to take care when using `this`.   Better to pass it in as an argument to the endless function.

```
$(this).css("left","100px");

function endless(elem){
    $(elem).animate(
        { left:'-=100px' },
        "linear",
        5000,
        function() {
            $(elem).css('left','100px');
            endless(elem);
        }
     );
};
endless(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to call endless() from within a callback.

```
function endless(item) {
  $(item).animate({"left": "-=100px"}, 5000, "linear", function(){
    $(item).css("left","100px");
    endless(item);
  });
}

endless($(".myBox"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `$(this)` with the selector to element that you want to animate.

Answer (score 0):

Great! this is exactly what i searched for, but now,

i finally figured how to toggle it. with the following function, call endless(0) to stop, and endless(1) to enable animation loop.

```
//loop animation forever
//args: takes 1 to loop, 0 to stop
function endless(loop)
{ 
  //animate forever
  if (loop==1)
  {
 $('#alink').animate(
  {'opacity':'toggle'}, 
  1000, 
   function () { endless(1) }
  ); 
  }
  //stop animation
  else
  {
 $('#alink').css('opacity',1).stop();
  }

}; 


//sample call
$('#alink').toggle(function(){ endless(1) },function(){ endless(0) });
```

thanx for initial code!